# VB Count query result in a textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I want to populate the result of an SQL count query on a Access database in a textbox showing how many results there are. For example I have a code number inputted into the database 200 time, i want the textbox to show 200.

Heres my code so far:

```
    ID = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    fn = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    ln = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    SKU = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
    FC = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value


    Dim countNoTwo As String = "SELECT COUNT skuNo FROM table WHERE skuNo = " & SKU & ""
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(duraGadgetDB)
    Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(countNoTwo, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "dura")
    connection.Close()

   txtbox1.Text
```

How do i bind the result of the dataset to the txtbox1.Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
txtbox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

- First, do not use string concatenation to build sql commands
  (reason=[Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) + Parsing problems)
- Second, if your command returns only one single result you could use
  [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)
- Third, use the [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to be sure that your connection and
  commands are correctly disposed after use

  ```
  Dim countNoTwo As String = "SELECT COUNT skuNo FROM table WHERE skuNo = ?"
  Using connection As New OleDbConnection(duraGadgetDB)
      Using command As New OleDbCommand(countNoTwo, connection)
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", SKU)
         connection.Open()
         Dim result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())
         txtbox1.Text = result.ToString
      End Using
  End Using
  ```